# How to add a resource as a binding in datagrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid, resources

This is a part of my code:

```
<ribbon:RibbonWindow x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
    x:Name="RibbonWindow"
Width="850" Height="600">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <sys:Int32 x:Key="Timestep">0</sys:Int32>

            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsNodes" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    ...

    <DataGrid x:Name="NodeDataGrid" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="Linen" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsNodes}}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Node" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" SortDirection="Ascending" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="X" Binding="{Binding Path=Position.X, StringFormat=\{0:F\}}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Y" Binding="{Binding Path=Position.Y, StringFormat=\{0:F\}}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Z" Binding="{Binding Path=Position.Z, StringFormat=\{0:F\}}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pressure (s)" Binding="{Binding Path=Results[{DynamicResource Timestep}].PressureSupply, StringFormat=\{0:F\}}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    ...
</ribbon:RibbonWindow>
```

Everything works, except this line:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Pressure (s)" Binding="{Binding Path=Results[{DynamicResource Timestep}].PressureSupply, StringFormat=\{0:F\}}" />
```

However, this works (I replaced {DynamicResource Timestep} with 0):

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Pressure (s)" Binding="{Binding Path=Results[0].PressureSupply, StringFormat=\{0:F\}}" />
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, indexers must be compile-time constants, so there is no way to do what you're attempting. The workaround will depend on your exact requirements, but you could have a property with a well-known name that exposes the correct result based on the current time step.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did as you said as a workaround and it works. It doesn't look as good as I want it to, but it gets the job done.